# NpmJs registry after delete still have my package

Tags: npm-install

I had published a package on Npm 4-5 months ago. The package name was *transaction-handler-ts*.
The problem was that my boss did not want the package to be public, so I deleted it. Since the package was no more on Npm, I decided to install the package on my projects directly from Bitbucket.

> npm install bitbucket:dummy/transaction-handler-ts#develop

It worked fine, until today.

Now, every time I try to install the package *transaction-handler-ts* from Bitbucket, it gave me an error.

> npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

It is like there is no package.json.

After a while I found why.
The npm application tries to find my package on the registry, and the problem is that it succeed (it should not be there, I deleted it).
https://registry.npmjs.org/transaction-handler-ts

At this point, npm do not care if I have indicated the repo on Bitbuket, it will try to get the package from the registry.
The problem in this case is that the package does not exist, so it probably download an empty folder.

I solved by changing the project name(from *transaction-handler-ts* to *transaction-handler-ts-two*), so npm will not find the package on the registry.

Did you know about other solutions? I also wrote an e-mail to NpmJs in order to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using Yarn instead of Npm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).